# Highcharts using database data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, highcharts

I am using HighCharts to display data from my MongoDB. Most of the time, I am returning simple data and I can get it displayed in the chart with no issue. In this one particular case, I am returning more complex data and I cannot get it to populate, so I;m obviously missing something.

Essentially, I query the database for a range of dates. In my program, I take a snapshot every 15 minutes of things like # of employees at work, so each day has 96 entries. This is a snapshot of the data I am returning:

```
 [{date: "2017-06-15T03:00:00.000Z",…}, {date: "2017-06-16T03:00:00.000Z", result: [,…]},…]
0
:
{date: "2017-06-15T03:00:00.000Z",…}
1
:
{date: "2017-06-16T03:00:00.000Z", result: [,…]}
date
:
"2017-06-16T03:00:00.000Z"
result
:
[,…]
0
:
{capture: "2017-06-16T00:00:00.000-03:00", sector: 5, cjs: ["FO", "TU", "HI", "ZV", "MI"], sitting: 5,…}
1
:
{capture: "2017-06-16T00:15:00.000-03:00", sector: 5, cjs: ["TU", "HI", "MI", "FO", "ZV"], sitting: 5,…}
2
:
{capture: "2017-06-16T00:30:00.000-03:00", sector: 5, cjs: ["MI", "FO", "ZV", "HI", "TU"], sitting: 5,…}
3
:
{capture: "2017-06-16T00:45:00.000-03:00", sector: 5, cjs: ["FO", "ZV", "HI", "TU", "MI"], sitting: 5,…}
4
:
{capture: "2017-06-16T01:00:00.000-03:00", sector: 5, cjs: ["FO", "ZV", "HI", "TU", "MI"], sitting: 5,…}
5
:
{capture: "2017-06-16T01:15:00.000-03:00", sector: 5, cjs: ["MI", "FO", "ZV", "HI", "TU"], sitting: 5,…}
6
:
{capture: "2017-06-16T01:30:00.000-03:00", sector: 5, cjs: ["MI", "FO", "ZV", "HI", "TU"], sitting: 5,…}
7
:
{capture: "2017-06-16T01:45:00.000-03:00", sector: 5, cjs: ["MI", "FO", "ZV", "HI", "TU"], sitting: 5,…}
```

As you can see, the data returns the date and an array called result. Inside this array is the data I want to access in the chart. I would like my X axis to list the capture times (every 15 minute increment) and the Y axis to list the sector count for each 15 minute increment.

My code for HighCharts is this:

```
function loadData() {
                                    var url = 'http://maccdx170131:4567/api/v1/sat/sectorutilization' + "?sdate=" + $('#sdate').val();
                                    url = url + "&edate=" + $('#edate').val();
                                    var date = new Array();

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {



                                            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {



                                                date.push ([new Date(data[i].result.capture).getTime(), data[i].result.sector]);
                                            }


                                            // draw chart
                                            $('#sc_bar').highcharts({
                                                chart: {
                                                    type: "column"
                                                },
                                                tooltip: {
                                                    pointFormat: "Staff: {point.y:,.0f} people"
                                                },
                                                credits: {
                                                    enabled: false
                                                },
                                                title: {
                                                    text: "Sector Utilization"
                                                },
                                                xAxis: {
                                                    type: 'datetime',
                                                    labels: {
                                                        format: '{value:%Y-%m-%d}',
                                                        rotation: 45
                                                    },
                                                    title: {
                                                        text: "Date"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                yAxis: {
                                                    title: {
                                                        text: "Sector Count"
                                                    }

                                                },
                                                series: [{
                                                    name: 'Sector Utilization',


                                                    data : date
                                                }]
                                            });
                                        });
                                    }
```

I know the current script for Highcharts is incorrect, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any ideas would be appreciated!!

Comment: The piece of data, that you provided does not tell anything. Please, post a piece of an exemplary data in a form of a JSON.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried changing the name of the variable you're putting into your chart data? It's possible "date" is a reserved keyword and that your code may be expecting a date value. Perhaps another name, such as "myChartDate". It's at least worth a shot. Also, if you have a fiddle of your work, adding that to your question would be really helpful.